# TypeScript says 'Object is possibly null' even though I explicity set it

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have an interface `PropertyValue` where the property `descr_json` is either an object, or null:

```
export interface Property {
    descr_json: Array<string>;
    descr: string;
    id: number;
}

export interface PropertyValue {
    descr_json: { [key: string]: string } | null;
    descr: string | number | null;
    id?: number;
}
```

Then in my code, at some point I try to add values to the `descr_json` property of a `PropertyValue` object:

```
if (property.descr_json && property.descr_json.length) {
    propertyValue.descr_json = {};
    property.descr_json.forEach(subProperty => {
        propertyValue.descr_json[subProperty] = '';
    });
}
```

But inside the `forEach`, TS complains that `propertyValue.descr_json` is possibly null, even though I explicity set it to an empty object on the previous line.

I could of course surround it with an extra `if` statement to check that `descr_json` is not, in fact, null, but this seems superfluous as *I already know this*.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `descr_json[subProperty]` thus `descr_json` has no reference to that right? so it is undefined

Comment: You use `.length` and `.forEach()` on an object ?

Comment: No, `property.descr_json` is an array :) `pValues.descr_json` is an object.

Comment: You show two vars `property` and `pValues` but only one interface `PropertyValue` and no type declartions (on assignment or anywhere). How would we know how to debug this?

Comment: My bad, I made the assumption that the objects had the same shape since they had the same property `descr_json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the [non null assertion operator](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/non-null-assertion-operator.html#:%7E:text=may%20be%20used%20to%20assert,variable%20cannot%20be%20null%2Fundefined.) to tell the transpiler that even though it could be null please just treat it as definitely not null,

in the situation where you need it to be treated as "really not null" postfix it with the non null assertion operator (exclamation mark)

I don't think the transpiler cares whether you have defined it or not, it just only cares what the type is and if its `nullable` in the typescript sense of the word, (i.e. number? or string?) then its type actually be `string | null` or `number | null` and the transpire won't care whether you have *explicitly set it or not*. This is what I believe, someone correct me if I'm wrong

```
  var x : string | null = null
  var y = x.substring(0, x.length / 2); // oop! it could be null compilation error
  var y = x!.substring(0, x!.length / 2); // use of assert non null operator prevents transpilation error
```

Another possible alternative would be to use a correctly typed temporary object and then assign that to `descr_json`

```
const temp: { [key: string]: string } = {};
property.descr_json.forEach(subProperty => {
  temp[subProperty] = '';
});
pValues.descr_json = temp;
```