# TypeScript 3.9.7 optional chaining warning in Vue 3.0.0.rc-5

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur

Getting Vetur error "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'." on lines that should be OK. I do have "Use Workspace Dependencies" checked in Vetur's VS Code Settings.

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "FormGroup",
  setup(_, { emit, slots }) {
    const validationErrorFree = () => {
      const vnodes = slots?.default() // <-- Vetur errors on slots?.default()
      const formInputs = vnodes.filter(
        (vnode) => vnode?.componentOptions?.tag === "FormInput",
      )
      ...
```

Shouldn't Vetur understand TypeScript optional chaining? I also tried adding

```
if (slots === undefined) return true
```

before the line that shows the error (and it didn't change anything). Same thing with wrapping:

```
if (slots !== undefined) {
```

around the function's interior. Any thoughts on what I overlooked?

Comment: use the non-null assertion operator `! ` to tell the transpiler even though this could be null, please treat it as not null. You can use the non-null assertion operator to gether with the null propogation/ optional chaining operator, although I forget which way round they go e.g. (either ?! or !?). Please check the next comment where there's a good answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript says 'Object is possibly null' even though I explicity set it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246929/typescript-says-object-is-possibly-null-even-though-i-explicity-set-it)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `!` [non null assertion operator](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/non-null-assertion-operator.html#:%7E:text=may%20be%20used%20to%20assert,variable%20cannot%20be%20null%2Fundefined.) `slots!.default()` to assert that `Really! I'm not null`

Please bare in mind that you should make pretty sure you know as its not going to be null, because otherwise you will get an error like cannot invoke `default()` on undefined.

It might be wise to cater for the eventuality in which it is null, and you can use the null assertion operator after the check to ensure its not null.

Comment: While slots!?.default() also showed an error, slots.default!() works. Want to revise your answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Ah perhaps its the exact version of TS your using, if that works Ill revise the answer

Comment: Yep, slots.default!() works with TS 3.9.7 - thanks!

Comment: I have just looked and I'm using `TS ^3.9.3`, perhaps the behaviour has changed and they no longer allow these two operators to be used together

Comment: Ah yes in 3.9 they [introduced this change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#parsing-differences-in-optional-chaining-and-non-null-assertions) which prevented use of these operators together as babel and users found this counter intuitive. So it seems this was a short lived combination that explains why I haven't found many materials about its usage online